# select next occurence of a word when using multiple cursors

Tags: visual-studio-code

From the bellow screen shot you can see that I have placed multi-cursor one multiple lines.

[image]

I want the next occurrence of `"` to be selected on each line for each cursor. I know I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> for selecting next occurrence. But it only works for single cursor. What is the solution for multi-cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v0.11.0 and the command `moveby.regex` you can move multiple cursors based on a regular expression.

The regular expression can be fixed in the keybinding or asked from the user.

For fixed regex use a key binding like:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": "\"",
      "properties": ["next", "start"]
    }
  }
```

To ask for a regex use a key binding like:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "ask": true,
      "properties": ["next", "start"]
    }
  }
```

In the Inputbox enter the regular expression in a non-escaped form. In a JSON files you need to escape the `"` and `\` characters.

In a later version the command `selectby.regex` will also support multi cursor.